# Selected value not changing when Gridview is re-ordered

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, gridview

When I select a row from my gridview by clicking on a linkbutton called 'Modify' and is the last cell in the row. Using the code below I can retrieve the key value from within the GridView1_RowCommand sub and move to the modify screen with the correct data.

```
    Dim r As Integer = e.CommandArgument        
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = r
    Dim Company As String = GridView1.SelectedDataKey(0).ToString
    ModifyDetail(Company)
```

However if I re-order the Gridview from a search option as below

```
    SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = NewSearchStr
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

When I try to access the first row it returns the first row value from the original Gridview and not from the re-ordered one. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a persistence issue. SelectCommand is not persisted in ViewState for security reasons, so you may have to persist and assign the DataSource to NewSearchStr each time the Grid is initialized.

see [VB Gridview selects wrong row for editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949826/vb-gridview-selects-wrong-row-for-editing/6950171#6950171)