# Filtered Gridview does edit correct row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview that works fine with SQLDataSource. Edit, Delete buttons works perfectly.
However, when I search any record and try to edit that record, the gridview opens up the first row in the edit mode.
I don't know what i have done wrong.

Here is my code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Customer_id"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" 
        PageSize="5" Width="873px" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
                        CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_id" HeaderText="Customer_id" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="Customer_id" InsertVisible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Name" HeaderText="Customer_Name" 
                SortExpression="Customer_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer_Type" HeaderText="Customer_Type" SortExpression="Customer_Type" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Overline="True" Font-Size="Large" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the Code Behind looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vs = (string)ViewState["buttonClicked"];
    string isEditing = (string)ViewState["isEditing"];
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (vs == "False")
        {
            RadioButtonListChanged();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (vs == "True")
        {
            btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void RadioButton1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonListChanged();

}

private void RadioButtonListChanged()
{
    ViewState["buttonClicked"] = "False";

    string sqlString;

    if (RadioButton1.SelectedItem.Text != "All")
    {
        sqlString = "Select * from customers where status='True' and  customer_type = '" + RadioButton1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' order by customer_name";
    }
    else
    {
        sqlString = "Select * from customers where  status='True' order by customer_name";
    }

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlString;
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ViewState["buttonClicked"] = "True";

    string sqlString;
    sqlString = "Select * from customers where status='True' and customer_name like '%" + txtCustomerName.Text + "%' order by customer_type, customer_name";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlString;
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  Always use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: its going to be an intranet application, so it doesnt really matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here
[Gridview Selects Wrong Row For Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949826/vb-gridview-selects-wrong-row-for-editing)

in page_load event

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = (string)Session["sqlString"];
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
}
```

and when i am searching i did this in button event

```
Session["sqlString"] = sqlString;
```

That wasn't simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the grid again in each post back, so the current row index is set to zero every time and this causes the first row to be edited.
Change you code to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (!IsPostBack)
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. I search a record first, then click on Edit button, but it doesn't edit that record, it takes me back to the first record.

Comment: That's also becuase you bind the grid again in the search handler.

Comment: Cancel the edit after search was clicked by setting `gridView.EditIndex = -1`. It doesn't make sense to leave the grid in edit mode after search brings new rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your code a little bit from:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vs = (string)ViewState["buttonClicked"];
    string isEditing = (string)ViewState["isEditing"];
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (vs == "False")
        {
            RadioButtonListChanged();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (vs == "True")
        {
            btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string vs = (string)ViewState["buttonClicked"];
            string isEditing = (string)ViewState["isEditing"];
            if (**!IsPostBack**)                     
                **^^^**
 /*just bind gridview when page is not 
        postback this will not bind oyur gridview on your every request*/
                if (vs == "False")
                {
                    RadioButtonListChanged();
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                else if (vs == "True")
                {
                    btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: i tried that too adity, but wasn't working. anyway I've got the answer myself. thx man.

Comment: thats nice you got your solution.